# Hyper-V Connection Issue / New Machines cannot connet to internet

Tags: hyper-v, internet-connection

I am working on a Windows Server 2019 Machine using Hyper-V for our VMs. Some time ago, all of the sudden I lost the Network Connection on all our VMs. An external Sysadmin solved the issue by deleting all our existing virtual switches and adding a new switch using PowerShell as admin with following commands:

```
New-VMSwitch -SwitchName "intSwitch" -SwitchType Internal
Get-NetAdapter (Read out IfIndex)
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 172.18.12.209 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex 51
New-NetNat -Name intSwitch -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 172.18.12.0/24
```

After Setting up the new IP-Configuration (Correct Standardgateway, Subnetmask and DNS Settings)  on all VMs everything worked fine again. Now after one week I Need to install a new VM for testing purposes. After full Serversetup for Windows Installation and Setting IP-Configuration I cannot get my new VM connected to the Internet. I am Pretty sure, that I am doing something wrong, but cannot find out what exactly.
My Current IP-Configuration on the VM is as follows:

[image: Ip-Configuration on new VM]

Here is my intSwitch Configuraion:

[image: IntSwitch Configuration]

I also turned off Windows Defender Firewall. The old VMs still got an Internet Connection.
The last Thing I tried is to take a working VM, Fresh Windwos Installation and IP-Config and end up with no Internet Connection again.

I cannot ping the Standard Gateway (Timeout error or Destination Host Unreachable) or 8.8.8.8 or any other Ip address (Destination Host Unreachable).

Comment: Are you sure that the new VM has the internal vswitch connected to it?

Comment: Yes it is, checked it now. Is there a way to set up DHCP for the vswitch? @Miket25

Comment: DHCP isn't managed by vswitch. Vswitch only forwards packets at the L2 layer.

Comment: I thougt the switch Acts like a router, thank you for the Information.

Comment: Ok I found something strange. I checked the NAT-Sessions on the vswitch using Get-NetNatSession. There are 3 active sessions, 1 from the old Machine with working active Connections and 2from the new Machine. In the fields ExternalDestinationAddress and InternalDestinationAddress the old Machine has some external IP-Address, but the new machine, which doesn´t get any Connection has 178.18.12.255. This can´t be true. Do you Maybe know, what is going wrong here? @Miket25